# eclipseでatomのマルチカーソル機能をもたせることは可能ですか？

Tags: eclipse

eclipseのショートカット機能を調べていたら、マルチカーソル機能はどうやらないみたいです。
しかし、外国の方がgithubでなにか公開しているみたいなのですが、使い方がわかりません。

eclipseでマルチカーソル機能を実現することは可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: Bugzillaに登録されているチケットを見る限り、現状は無理そうに見えますね… [Bug 466532 Support multiple carets/cursors for text insertion (like in Sublime or VS Code)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=466532)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。1個1個ボタンを押していきましたがダメでした。なんとかすればできるみたいなのでまた力いれて調べてみようと思います。

Answer (score 1):

自分自身使いこなしているわけではないのですが、
`Shift + Alt + a` でブロック選択ができます。
変更したい個所を範囲で囲って複数行同時に編集することができます。

また、変数名であれば下記記事の `Shift + Alt + r` で同時編集可能なので使いこなせればかなり時短になりそうです。
[新人研修でドヤ顔で披露したらウケたEclipseのショートカット集/第3位 alt + shift + r 名前変更](https://qiita.com/arai-wa/items/c2eb7387b5bf37b4ace4#%E7%AC%AC3%E4%BD%8D-alt--shift--r-%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4)